# To change a custom widget in a plutter using an if statement

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to show a_page if the ageValue value is less than 13, b_page if it is less than 15, and c_page if it is less than 17

```
final ageValue = 0;
final age;
if(ageValue <= 17){
   age = const c_page;
} else if(ageValue <= 15{
   age = const b_page;
} else if(ageValue <= 13{
   age = const a_page;
} else {

}
```

If you use age after that, you will get the following error

error `The final variable 'age' can't be read because it's potentially unassigned at this point. (Documentation)  Ensure that it is assigned on necessary execution paths.`

If you give me an if statement according to the ageValue, the age changes, and I thought that using age would allow me to take and use custom widgets without any major problems. But it was wrong and I couldn't find a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you're tying to add value in `age` variable which is not assigned yet,

You can either make the `age` variable as `late final` so we are assuring the compiler that this variable will be assigned in the future.
Or Remove the final and add some initialise value to it.

And going through your code i can see your conditions are also wrong; See we take your code and assume ageValue is 12 then it goes to the first condition which is `ageValue <= 17` which is true, 12 < 17 is true so the a_page will be shown which wrong, it should show the c_page.

So It should be like below:

```
  final ageValue = 0;
  late final age;

  if (ageValue <= 13) {
    age = c_page;
  } else if (ageValue <= 15) {
    age = b_page;
  } else if (ageValue <= 17) {
    age = a_page;
  } else {
    
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

in dart language when you define a final variable, you should initialize it at compile time, but you can late it, late means that you will initialize it at runtime before first call, try this code:

```
final ageValue = 0;
late final Widget age;
if(ageValue <= 17){
age = const c_page;
} else if(ageValue <= 15{
age = const b_page;
} else if(ageValue <= 13{
age = const a_page;
} else {

}
```